# SQL Server 2012 Uninstall Error

Tags: sql-server, uninstallation, sql-server-2012

After uninstalling one instance from SQL Server 2012, I tried to uninstall the second one but this time an error pop ups saying I don't meet the requirements which is not true since I was using SQL before.

Have anyone encountered this problem before?

System Specifications:

Intel Core i3-2300 @ 3.10 GHz
2.00GB(1.82 GB Usable)
32 bit Operating System

SQL Server Edition: Enterprise

**Error: The operating system on this computer does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2012. For Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 operating systems, Service Pack 2or later is required. For Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, Service Pack 1 or later is required. For more information, see Hardware and Software Requirements for installing SQL Server 2012 at:**

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=195092

Comment: Never had this, but maybe the first uninstall removed some files that the setup checks? Did you check MSDN about this problem?

Comment: Can you run a repair operation on the first instance to shake things loose?  That or reapply/repair service packs.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231731.aspx I've checked this link at Uninstall an Existing Instance of SQL Server (Setup) but had no luck with that. I will try and do a repair to see if that works.

Comment: RThomas Yes I can run a repair operation. Currently I have made a repair on existing instances of SQL Server 2012, but still no luck with this. Unfortunately I can't reapply the service pack since this is our client computer.

Comment: I am getting the same with express edition. cant get it to uninstall no matter what I do. If I find a solution I will post it here.

Comment: I posted a link to the solution but apparently the mod didnt like it. It fixed it for me so I will post it here. go to the install folder and right click on the setup.exe in the setup bootstrap folder. right click > properties > set compatibility to vista sp2 and then run un-installer.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/707706/unable-to-uninstall-sql-server-2012-rc0-from-control-panel . One of its workarounds (run `setup.exe /Action=Uninstall`) worked for me - apparently skipped the faulty OS check.

Comment: @JohnS Your answer can be undeleted if you post the relevant information from the link into the answer. Just posting a link really helps no one; especially if that link moves, dies, or intermittently fails.

Answer (score 19):

This post would be more appropriate as a comment, but I cannot post comments, so here it goes.

I have had the same problem. I run Windows 7 with SP1. I accidentally installed the 32 bit version, instead of the 64, of SQL Server Express 2012 SP1 on my 64 bit system, and could not remove it due to the above error.

I have followed John S's advice and changed the compatibiliby mode of setup.exe to Vista SP2.
On my machine, this file was located in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap.

After that I was able to run the "Remove" option from the control panel with success.

***Another fix:*** (since this didn't work for me) - you need the SQL2012 with SP3 Install Media for the version you have installed. SP3 doesn't have that bug with the installer so just mount the ISO or browse to the extracted media and run F:\setup.exe /ACTION=uninstall  - that worked for me perfectly after A LOT of seraching. This post helped me get there - thank you. (I'm editing because I don't have reputation!).

Comment: I got this same error on Windows 8.1 after installing VS2013.  I have seen where some state it requires a clean OS to install SQL Server.  However, setting the compatibility settings to windows 8 and running as administrator got me past this error message.

Comment: My error was similar and I tried this, but no success. This did lead me to copying the setup files(everything in the x64 folder) from my DVD over to the SQL setup folder `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap` and that worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether have you solved the problem or not ..I solved the problem by following way: 
Here is the details I have tried:

You need to go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2012

And there click on the setup.exe and go to compatibility tab on properties And check Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows X(your Windows Version).

Now if you can uninstall it correctly.